# How to replace by order

Tags: php, replace

How can I replace something orderly? for example:

```
$var = "let's count: ?, ?, ?";
```

Now I want to replace it by 1, 2, 3 for the result to be "let's count 1, 2, 3". How can I do that? I can't replace by "%s" and use vsprintf() with an array because I wanna respect integers and floats. But I want to do it with an array. For example:

```
$var = replace( $var, "?", array(1, 2, 3) );
```

How can I do it? I can't get any idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
$var = "let's count: ?, ?, ?";
$numbers = array(1,2,3);

foreach( $numbers as $number ) {
  $var = preg_replace("/\?/", $number, $var, 1);
}
```

Comment: Result: let's count: 1, 1, 1 :) I have thought that and it didn't work. :/

Comment: This clearly won't work, `str_replace` replaces all occurrences at once.

Comment: Oops, forgot the last parameter to str_replace.  Check the edited version.

Comment: Haha, you're right.  I'll just use preg_replace  :)

Comment: This version is actually tested and works.  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: That's funny, when I read your answer I thought to myself "Did he mean to use preg_replace instead of str_replace"?

Comment: Check please my answer)

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks you. :P I didn't know the $limit argument

Answer (score 4):

PHP is fun.

```
$var = "let's count: ?, ?, ?";
$replace = array('1', '2', '3');
$needle = '?';

foreach($replace as $val) {
    $var[strpos($var, $needle)] = $val;
}
```

Comment: Oh, good answer.  I like this more  :)  Probably faster than preg_replace.

Comment: It works perfectly when you try to replace just 1 letter. However it's faster preg_replace. :P

Comment: `array('11', '12', '13')` returns `let's count: 1, 1, 1`

Answer (score 3):

Since `strpos()` will return the first result of the occurance you could do something like this:

```
$var = "let's count: ?, ?, ?";
$index = 1;
while(strpos($var, '?'))
{
    $var[strpos($var, '?')] = $index;
    $index++;
}
echo $var;
```

Comment: You might want to update to `$pos = strpos($var, '?')` so you don't have to call the function multiple times, though I understand its purpose as the while condition. The other issue is that the code will only return integers based on the count, rather than arbitrary values.

Answer (score 2):

Why you need use **substr_count** or **strpos** in answers above? You can use simple `for` for this task. Look into my example.) ***This is the most fastest solution for performance***.

```
$var = "let's count: ?, ?, ?";
$replace = array(1,2,3);

for($i=0, $r=0; $i< strlen($var); $i++){

$var[$i] = '?' === $var[$i] ? $replace[$r++] : $var[$i] ;

}

var_dump($var);
```

Result:

```
string(20) "let's count: 1, 2, 3"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "lets count: ?, ?, ?";
$search = "/\?/";
$replace = array(1,2,3);

if( is_array($replace) ) {
  $search = array_fill(0, count($replace), $search);
}

echo preg_replace( $search, $replace, $str, 1);

//output: lets count: 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = "let's count: ?, ?, ?";
$cnt = substr_count($var, '?');

for ($i=1;$i<=$cnt;$i++)
    $var = substr_replace($var, $i, strpos($var, '?'), 1);

echo $var; //let's count: 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: @vonbrand Not sure what you mean... can you elaborate?